# Problem with colliders in Unity (melee RPG)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I'm making a game in Unity and have been having a lot of trouble with setting up a way of detecting melee collisions.
Having researched every suggestion from other people asking about this, none seemed to work, and something that should be simple to implement has proven ridiculously hard.
The main problem is that collisions simply do not register all of the time.

I was using the `OnTriggerEnter` method for collision detection but this consistently fails to detect all of the collisions. Along with every other method i have attempted including physical collisions using every combination of collision detection.

I then changed this to the `OnTriggerStay` method, and this detects either 100% or close to 100% of collisions, although i'm not happy with the workaround since i see no logical reason why OnTriggerEnter is not working.

BOTH methods present another problem however.  That is that often the collision is triggered multiple times during the same weapon attack.
So if i swing my sword at an enemy, it will trigger twice in the same swing, and damage the enemy twice.

My collision code is

```
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
        {
            if (canDamage == true)
            {

                float damage = wielder.GetComponent<BaseStats>().GetStat(Stat.Damage); 
              
                other.gameObject.GetComponent<Health>().TakeDamage(wielder, damage);
               
                
            }
               
        }
```

Could anyone suggest a way to add to this code that would make it so that the first collision would be accepted, but then any further collisions (during that particular swing of the weapon) would not be.

Also, keep in mind that in this game it is possible for a single weapon swing to hit MULTIPLE enemies. So it would need allow for hitting enemy 1,  then blocking enemy 1 from taking further damage,  but still allowing the possibility of enemy 2 or enemy 3 etc from taking damage if it comes into contact with them.

Or alternatively, any feedback on the collision system in general and suggestions for a better alternative would be appreciated :)

Comment: Did you alter the physics of your project in any way?

Comment: When i was first looking for answers someone suggestion a different physics setting, which i tried and it failed to work so i changed it back... at least i think i did.

If i remember correctly, it was the 'contacts generation'  which is currently set to Persistent Contact Manifold

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

1. Make sure your colliders are not very small in size. Unity physics engine doesn't work well with tiny colliders. Its better to scal up everything if necessary. Play with it.
2. Change the `collisionDetectionMode` of rigidbodies to `CollisionDetectionMode.ContinuousDynamic` for fast moving objects like your sword, and for other objects which these need to collide with like your enemy, set it to `CollisionDetectionMode.Continuous`. Try different combinations if this doesn't work. It may affect performance. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-collisionDetectionMode.html).
3. To solve the problem with hitting multiple times, I would simply create a list of gameobjects that entered my sword trigger during the attack and before I damage the enemy I would check if its already on that list. If its on the list don't take the damage. If not take the damage and add it to the list. Clear the list every time you start the attack again or when the attack is over.